# How to understand "-metr-", as a root?

Tags: prefixes, roots

*-Metr-*, as a root, from http://www.prefixsuffix.com/rootchart.php:

> metr: admeasure, apportion. E.g., metrics, asymmetric, parametric, telemetry

"Admeasure, apportion" means distribution. So I can't understand: how is this meaning of *-metr-* demonstrated in the examples "metrics, asymmetric, parametric, telemetry"?

*Metr*, as a word, from http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metr:

> metr:   meter (unit of length).     measuring tape, measuring rule.

I feel this meaning of *metr* makes more sense in the examples "metrics, asymmetric, parametric, telemetry".

So how shall I understand the first source?

Comment: Note that the Wiktionary entries are all from languages where the spelling of ‘meter/metre’ just happens to be _metr_. It is not an English word at all.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from a confusion between the two roots **μέτρησις** and **μετρητής**.

The first means "meter" as a unit of measure, how tall you are for instance.

The second means "portion", what you are given in a fast-food for instance.

Comment: Thanks!Which one makes sense in the examples "metrics, asymmetric, parametric, telemetry"?

Comment: It is funny to note that "kilometer", or other obvious variants of "kilomètre", is an universal word, except ... in Greek, where it would not make sense (One thousand of units ? a portion for a "kilo", what sort of animal is that ?). Regretfully, they use "km". The French Convention, which fixed the word "mètre" as a concrete thing and not an abstract concept, is responsible.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now and don't have easy access to any resources, but _μέτρητης_ does not look right to me (ultrapreantepenultimate mora accented?)—should it not be _μέτρησις_ or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The table is incorrect. The *metr* in words like *[metrics](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=metrics), [geometry](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=geometry),* and *[metronome](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=metronome)* is not a separate root, but simply a variant of [*meter*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=meter) (from the Greek *metron* “measure” or *metra* “portion”).

The common suffix [*-metry*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=-metry) specifically means “measurement,” as used in *telemetry* “measurement from a distance” and *geometry* “measurement of land.” The *-metric* suffix is simply the adjectival form of *-meter* (*parametric*) or *-metry* (*asymmetric* “no equal measurement”).

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for some reliable sources of roots, bases, suffixes. If the table is not a good one, what would you suggest?

Comment: I recommend the Online Etymology Dictionary linked from my post.

Comment: Thanks! I will use it for the future. How do you think about the etymology part of each word by Wiktionary?